# Cart Throb: The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts. 10413- when shipping is included

Tags: cartthrob, shipping

I thought I had this error fixed ages ago but found out I did not.
EE 2.5.2  CT 2.2.2

When checking out with paypal express I get the error

The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts. 10413

This error ONLY occurs when I have a shipping charge.  Currently shipping is defined per product.  **If Shipping is not required I do not get this error.**

SOLVED an EE and CT upgrade seemed to fix this issue

Comment: Peter, can you add your solution below as an answer and accept your answer as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an EE and CT upgrade seemed to fix this issue